# Must two public fields declared next to each other be "next to each other" in memory?

Tags: c++, memory

In C++, if I have a class like:

```
class Foo {
public:
  int a;
  char b;
private:
  char c;
};
```

Does that mean that `a` has to be next to `b` in memory when an instance of `Foo` is allocated?

I've been reading a bit of the standard [here (n4296)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf), and the only language I found was

> Nonstatic data members of a (non-union) class with the same access
>   control (Clause 11) are allocated so that later members have higher
>   addresses within a class object.

So that language sounds like it doesn't rule out potential orderings like "a,c,b" instead of the "a,b,c" or even "c,a,b" as you might expect.

I searched for the term `contiguous` which interestingly only appears 21 times in the standard, but I felt that they might've used a different terminology to describe the idea "two fields arranged in such a way that there are no other fields between them."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line immediately after the one you quoted answers this question:

> **The order of allocation** of non-static data members with different
>   access control **is unspecified**. Implementation alignment
>   requirements might cause two adjacent members **not to be allocated
>   immediately after each other**

So two fields declared next to each other may or may not be “next to each other” depending on the implementation of the compiler.